# Corda Performance lag on High volume transaction

Tags: corda

I did a Load test by sending around a few million records over a period of 12 hours , here is the analysis.

1. Hour 1 the transactions commits are very fast , within a few 100
   milliseconds. as the hours go by and the number of transactions
   committed to the corda DB increases so did the reduction in the
   performance of the Corda Node.
2. After Around 2 million transactions
   committed , the node efficiency goes down to about a few seconds per
   transaction. After DB refresh of the nodes  i.e resetting the DB to
   a version with no Data , the transactions execute again within the
   milliseconds range

Following is the query

1. Whether the MQ in the Corda Node impacts this ?
2. Any Corda Query that is causing the drop in performance ?

P.S : I am working with corda 3.3 enterprise version

Answer (score 0):

There might many factors to consider in this question. For example, how is your Cordapp written, what is the size of your node, Are your flows linear transactions, etc. Furthermore, we had boosted the performance since Corda(v4.x).

You can find more information on sizing and performance: https://docs.corda.r3.com/sizing-and-performance.html

Comment: I have separated the Cordapp , such that Flows are in 1 Jar , each of the Contract+Schema are in separate Jars. The transactions are not linear i.e they dont use each other as Input .